# How to find data from multiple tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose we have three tables:

**Table1**

```
|     c_id          |   categories     |   
|-------------------|------------------|
|      7            |       a          |     
|      4            |       b          |     
|      3            |       c          |
```

**Table2**

```
|     c_id          |   dup_id     |   
|-------------------|--------------|
|       9           |     10       |     
|       5           |      3       |     
|       6           |      2       |
```

**Table3**

```
|     c_id          |  description |   
|-------------------|--------------|
|      22           |     xxxx     |     
|       5           |     yyyy     |     
|      11           |     zzzz     |
```

Suppose if some of `c_id` in the Table1 equal to the `dup_id` in Table2, then we can find out the corresponding `c_id` of `dup_id`, and use that to find `description` in the Table3. What will be the optimal way to do this?

**Output:**

```
|     c_id          |  description |   
|-------------------|--------------|    
|       5           |     yyyy     |
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a straight forward join of 3 tables:

```
select Table2.c_id, description
from Table1
join Table2 on Table1.c_id = Table2.dup_id
join Table3 on Table2.c_id = Table3.c_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't is this is the optimal way or not but you can do it like this:

```
SELECT t2.dup_id,t3.description
FROM 
Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table3 t3
WHERE t2.dup_id = t1.c_id AND t3.c_id = t2.dup_id
```

Or you can do join

```
select t2.dup_id, t3.description
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.c_id = t2.dup_id
join Table3 t3 on t2.dup_id = t3.c_id
```

Answer (score 0):

-->Using MySQL JOIN<--
SELECT
table2.c_id,
table3.description
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.c_id=table2.c_id
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.dup_id=table1.c_id

-->Using Subquery<--
SELECT
table3_output.c_id,
table3_output.description
FROM(
SELECT table3.c_id,description,table2.dup_id
FROM table3
INNER JOIN table2 ON table3.c_id=table2.c_id
) AS table3_output
INNER JOIN table1 ON
table1.c_id=table3_output.dup_id

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your answer, checkout https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for guides. Also it would be much appreciated if you could elaborate on your code instead of answering only codes.